# How to solve this combination problem quickly?

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can 3 men and their wives be made stand in a line such that none of the 3 men stand in a position that is ahead of his wife?

What is the best way to tackle such problems?

```
 Here is how I am tackling this problem

    M1 M2 M3  -> Men
    W1 W2 W3  -> Wives

    a.
     1  2   3   4    5    6
     W1 M1  W2  M2   W3   M3     ->  


    With the above in mind, W1 M1 is a pair and W2 M2 is a pair, W3 M3 is a pair.
    so, there can be 3 interchanges - if we assume that W1 M1 stick to each other.

    b. 

     W1 W2  M1  M2   [W3   M3]

W1 W2 can interchange in 2 ways. 
M1 M2 can interchange in 2 ways 

4 ways..* 2 ( when W3 M3 will be at first) = 8 ways.  



    c.  W1 W2  W3  M1   M2   M3

    W1 W2 W3 can be arranged in 3 ways
    M1 M2 M3 can be arranged in 3 ways.
    total ways are 9 ways. 

    -----------------

    so adding all -  20 ways.


However, the answer is not 20 ways. What is wrong in my thought process here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good, if not the best, way to tackle this problem is pick two positions for the first couple to occupy, then another two for the second couple to occupy, which will leave just two positions for the third couple.  This can be done in

$${6\choose2}{4\choose2}{2\choose2}=15\cdot6\cdot1=90$$

ways.  Note that if you remove the condition that each man must stand behind his wife, the number of ways increases by a factor of $2\cdot2\cdot2=8$, which would give $90\cdot8=720$ ways, which makes sense since $720=6!$, which counts the number of ways of arranging $6$ people in a line with no restrictions.

Comment: Ah, I see paw88789 beat me by a minute.  Great minds, and all that....

Comment: I am not getting why divide by 2. How did you get that it should be divided by 2? You are saying for couple 1, they will be half time ahead and half time behind. How did you get that they will be half time ahead and behind?

Comment: @dexterous_stranger, where do you see a division by $2$?  Does paw88789's answer make more sense?

Comment: 6/2 then 4/2 then 2/2 . I am seeing division by 2 for each three position. Where one position is combined by the couple,

Comment: @dexterous_stranger, it sounds like you are unfamiliar with the notation for binomial coefficients.  The symbol ${5\choose 3}$, for example, doesn't mean $5/3$.  Is this what you are unclear on?

Comment: it's basically 5C3

Comment: @dexterous_stranger, yes, and the others are $6C2=15$, $4C2=6$, and $2C2=1$.  The combinatorial interpretation of binomial coefficients involves *counting*, not division (although the computation of them is often done with some division steps).  If you are still unclear on how my answer (and paw88789's) works, I'll try editing it with extra explanation.  Please let me know.

Comment: Ok, I understand C notation very well. Sorry, I didn't know the binomial notation. I might have studied but have forgot by this time. You can elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Choose two positions for man 1 and woman 1 (husband-wife pair).  $6\choose 2$ ways.  Put woman 1 in the earlier of these two positions.

Choose two remaining positions for man 2 and woman 2.  $4\choose 2$ ways.  Put woman 2 in the earlier of these two positions.

Put man 3 and woman 3 into the two remaining slots, with woman 3 in the earlier position.

${6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}$ ways to do the process.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two slips.
Firstly, you forgot WMWWMM. [edit, sorry, you didn't.  However, in b, there are three choices for which pair is together - you have W3M3 together, but it might be W1M1 or W2M2.]
Secondly, WMWMWM can be arranged in six ways, not three:
W1M1W2M2W3M3,
W1M1W3M3W2M2,
W2M2W1M1W3M3,
W2M2W3M3W1M1,
W3M3W1M1W2M2,
W3M3W2M2W1M1.
Similarly for WWWMMM.

Comment: What is the best way to tackle such questions? Do we need to make pairs? If we need to make pairs then what's the point of counting using combinations.

Comment: Your method is good. to check all possibilities.  I suggest, for this one, a shortcut:  Out of the 6!=720 arrangements, M1 is ahead of W1 in half, M2 is ahead of W2 in half, and M3 is ahead of W3 in half.  So only one eighth of the 720 are valid.

Comment: I didn't understand that - "Why should we divide by 8 here - 6!/ 2! 2! 2!?" You say that 2! are the ways where M1 W1 can be arranged. However, this shouldn't be. But, then why are we dividing it?

Comment: The 6! ways include both M1 before W1 and W1 before M1.  There is an equal number with M1 before W1 and with W1 before M1, so half of them have W1 before M1.  That leaves 360.  Then look at W2 and M2.