# man ahead of his wife

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways in which $3$ men and their wives can be arranged in a line such that none of the three men stand in a position that is ahead of his wife

what i try

let men be $M_{1},M_{2},M_{3}$ and wives be $W_{1},W_{2},W_{3}$

arrangements as

(i) $M_{1}W_{1}M_{2}W_{2}M_{3}W_{3}$ or

(ii) $M_{1}M_{2}M_{3}W_{1}W_{2}W_{3}$

ways total is $1+2!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!=73$

but original answer is different from mine How do i solve it Help me plese

Comment: You have to consider $M_1M_2W_2W_1M_3W_3$ and other such combinations.

Comment: This is duplicate...https://math.stackexchange.com/q/952432/610653